# Using Console.WriteLine within a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, logging

I have an external DLL whose source code is C#. From the documentation for the DLL, I determined that it writes its debug messages to the console using `Console.WriteLine`.

I'd like to use this DLL within a WinForms application. However, what I have discovered is that I cannot see the debug messages emitted by the DLL since a WinForms application does not have a console.

is there a way to capture those debug messages, perhaps even to a simple log file? Of course, using `ProcessInfo.RedirectStandartOutput` will not work as I do not use the DLL as a process.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Call [Console.SetOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx) with a TextWriter you control (e.g. a StringWriter).

Answer (score 4):

You would be best served using the System.Diagnostics namespace and Debug.WriteLine instead. Debug supports 'listeners' that can be added at run-time or via the app/web.config files. For example:-

```
  Debug.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener())
```

If you implement any custom debug logging as a trace listener, you can capture your trace messages application wide very easily.